# Override action in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In file '/wp-includes/comment-template.php', in function comment_form() exist action - 'do_action('comment_form_before')'. Below this action written code

```
<div id="respond" class="comment-respond">
<h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title"><?php comment_form_title( $args['title_reply'], $args['title_reply_to'] ); ?> <small><?php cancel_comment_reply_link( $args['cancel_reply_link'] ); ?></small></h3>
```

I want to replace all this code by my own code. How I can do it?

Comment: Open the file with the code, replace the code, save?

Comment: @PeeHaa only if the OP wants to lose their changes in the next upgrade of WordPress.  Best avoided if at all possible.

Comment: I can't. I'm making template.. I think, that replace all comment_form() function will be bad solution. May be possible to solve problem with hooks?

Comment: @user3724896 - is the code itself a problem, or just its apperance?  Can you hide it with CSS?  If not, the only thing I can think of would be to start output buffering the output in the `comment_form_before` hook, read (and close) the buffer in the `comment_form_after` hook, then manipulate the content before outputting it.  Very ugly way to do it though.

Comment: @Hobo It's appearance. I want to wrap this code in 'div' with my own classes, and add span blocks. I solved temporary this problem by replacing whole comment_form() function by my own, but I think, it's not right way..

Comment: you can just edit the post template and not call the normal wp comment template

Comment: @vico I made so now, copied standard comment_form() function in functions.php, renamed and edited it, called renamed function in comments.php. But standard comment_form() function is so big, I don't want to copy it whole in my functions.php, if needed to replace in it a few lines..